# Is there a Linux filesystem like 'tee'?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is there any existing filesystem for Linux that acts like tee and proxies file operations to two separate filesystems?

My immediate use would be writing to both a btrfs filesystem to experiment with stuff and an ext4 filesystem to have a stable backup in case I end up corrupting the btrfs.

Comment: Can you just make periodic backups?  Perhaps using something like borg/attic which backup things by computing checksums of blocks?

Comment: Close voters: a filesystem is a shopping request?  Can I buy me one of them at Amazon, and do they come in pink?

Comment: @fixer1234 He's asking for software.

Comment: What about RAID1?

Comment: @mdpc RAID is neither a backup nor a filesystem. One disk with a corrupted filesystem in RAID1 is every disk with a corrupted filesystem in RAID1.

Comment: Then look at mirrored LVM you can mirror more than one time.  BTW, if you wanted a BACKUP then I suggest that you state this in your posting.  You indicated a "tee" which to me implies a real-time duplication of data to one or more devices thus the suggestion of RAID1 or mirrored LVM.

Comment: BTW, the failure of one disk in a mirror does not affect the integrity of the non-mirrored set of disks (unless there is some other serious hardware or software bug).

Answer (score 1):

I have found [ChironFS](http://www.furquim.org/chironfs/index.en.html).

> It is a FUSE based filesystem. Its main purpose is to guarantee filesystem availability using replication. But it isn't a RAID implementation. RAID replicates DEVICES not FILESYSTEMS.

**Important: I haven't used it. I cannot guide you further at this moment.** I know this makes my answer mediocre quality at most.

Still, considering your case I have a general doubt. Any experiment with btrfs-specific features (like COW) would require one of the two:

- the "proxy filesystem" ability to pass it to underlying btrfs and to replicate/simulate/fake it with ext4 (e.g. simple copy instead of COW) in a smart way; but FUSE implements just common operations (like `open`, `chmod`, `mkdir`) in a custom way, this does not include btrfs-specific operations;
- direct access to btrfs (bypassing "proxy filesystem"), but this would easily break one-to-one correspondence to ext4.

For these reasons I think every existing solution (ChironFS or something else, if any) will not allow you to freely experiment with btrfs, unless it is written with btrfs in mind from the start. I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: ChironFS could be interesting to play with, but I am looking for something that would just duplicate the file operation calls to the kernel, and let the respective kernel FS drivers for the respective backend filesystems do the storage operations independently. It looks like ChironFS could almost do what I want, if I export the btrfs and ext4 filesystems via NFS then run ChironFS on top of the NFS exports, but I'd rather avoid the NFS middleman if I can.

Comment: @Gordon What makes you think NFS is a need? [This example](http://www.furquim.org/chironfs/howto.html#test) is done with local directories. Also [this list](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/wiki/Filesystems) claims that "the replicated filesystem may be of any kind you want; the only requisite is that you mount it.". I'd rather worry ChironFS seems abandoned since 2008…