# How do I "simply" "RAID 1" two USB drives without over-complicated schemes?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, usb, raid

**Update 1**:[ChironFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiron_FS) is really what I need, but it has been deprecated for more than 10 years now. I'm looking for the same, but still maintained.

I got two old USB keys and also two old hard drives going through their own USB adapters.

The goal is to "simply" do the same operations on both drives when I do something on either drive or another (e.g: copy, delete, edit, etc), but with these requirements:

- Must behave like RAID 1, but will use very little of its features (If I copy something on drive 1, do the same on drive 2 at the same time. Same goes for editing, removing data, `dd`, etc).
- No hardware-based solutions, only software ones
- The dumbed-down "RAID 1" won't care about the drives sizes (I will handle this myself. If one of the drive is full, just stop writing of both like it would do on one drive. If there's no data to remove on drive 2 but does on drive 1, just delete it on drive 1. Etc).
- It must **not** use special partitions (e.g. **no** LVM, no "RAID drive rebuilding" system" since I will manually rebuild it myself, etc)
- It must use standard partitions (ext4, ntfs, etc) but not partitions special features (e.g. BTRFS "RAID", etc).
- Must work on Linux, and on Widnows as optional.
- I do not care about speed transfers
- Simply ejecting one the USB drives will make the remaining one act like a normal/un-RAID-ed one.

This would works more like a "monkey see, monkey do" style of "dumbed down RAID 1" or some kind of "loosely linked asymmetric drives, but doing the exact same thing at the same time if it can". Is there any ways to do this ?

PS: There's some ways on the internet to do a "RAID 1" of USB drives from even 10 years ago, but they're all more like LVM-based answers. Which is **not** what I want.

Comment: In Linux this is almost trivial to implement via FUSE. Also check if ChironFS is what you need.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov You might as well make that a proper answer. This is exactly what ChironFS does.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Since chironFS is dead, is there any other way to do that ?

Comment: You seem to be trying to discount mdadm software RAID - why? You can access the underlying disks directly if RAID fails.

Comment: I wonder if modifying something like https://bartsimons.me/sync-folders-and-files-on-linux-with-rsync-and-inotify/ would solve your problem? (ie use inotify to copy when a file is added/changed)

Comment: @X.LINK As I said, it's not too hard to implement it by yourself. You can do that, for example, in Python, as there are AFAIK binding for FUSE.

Comment: @davidgo : Some reasons I listed cannot be donne with `mdadm` (e.g. no rebuilding system, no specific LVM partitions, can't natively use ntfs or ext4, no 100% asymmetric drives that I can manage myself, etc). `inotify` looks promising and I have yet to choose that or raw FUSE implementations.
@NikitaKipriyanov : I unfortunately don't know how to code, but if it's trivial enough I'll try it. Apart from python-fuse, can you somewhat accurately tell me what I'll have to look for too ?

Comment: While you don't want mdadm/LVM, perhaps a simple device-mapper mirror that you can create with `dmsetup` will suit (at least some of) you needs? (It makes use of a table from a file / stdin instead of metadata on the drives themselves, I think. So it's like "stateless" / "volatile".)

Comment: Just FYI, while you do need to contend with rebuilding when using an mdadm solution you dont need to use lvm, and it is totally practical to put an ext4 or fat or ntfs system directly on the md device - and you can read and write from the underlying disk directly - albeit breaking the raid and possibly requiring an offset in the mount command depending on the  metadata placement.  I worked out you are wanting a file rather then block level solution after my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

That one is easy implement in Linux via FUSE (Filesystem In UserspacE). It seems somebody already made it: check [chironfs](http://www.furquim.org/chironfs/index.en.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do. I also digged a bit ( https://superuser.com/questions/1128898/is-there-a-linux-filesystem-like-tee ) and found that chironfs has been dropped for a decade now. Sigh, so close...